# how to fix " Emulator: Warning: QXcbIntegration: Cannot create platform OpenGL context, neither GLX nor EGL are enabled ((null):0, (null))"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I'am working on xfce "Xubuntu", I have updated my android studio, and every time I execute any project with emulator I get this two errors:

> Emulator: Warning: QXcbIntegration: Cannot create platform OpenGL
>   context, neither GLX nor EGL are enabled ((null):0, (null))
>
> Emulator: emulator: ERROR: VkCommonOperations.cpp:496: Failed to
>   create Vulkan instance.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with Arch running Gnome 3 using Wayland. Forgive my ignorance, but I neither use XFCE nor *buntu so I must ask, are you using Wayland or XOrg/XServer? (just to rule out if it's a Wayland issue)

Comment: The same error appears for me since the latest Android Emulator update on Arch with XFCE and classic XOrg server.

Comment: I am on Arch with Gnome3 on XOrg and having the same issue. So, it's not specific to Wayland or XOrg.

Comment: Could it be that the problem is linked to not so new hardware? This is where I get it.

Comment: Same here, KDE Neon, Ryzen 3700X, Nvidia GTX970 - wouldn't call it not-so-new. Also, the issue is present on google issue tracker: [link] (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=qxcbintegration)

Comment: Same here, on Arch with Openbox and integrated Intel Graphics

Answer (score 3):

I got the first error.

> Emulator: Warning: QXcbIntegration: Cannot create platform OpenGL context, neither GLX >nor EGL are enabled ((null):0, (null))

The error remained but the emulator is running properly. I changed the following two settings with the next two values in the config.ini file from the avd folder.

hw.gpu.enabled = no

hw.gpu.mode = swiftshader_indirect

The avd folder should be located similarly:
/home/[your_linux_username]/.android/avd/Nexus_One_API_22.avd/

Nexus_One_API_22 is the name of the avd.

Comment: This did not fix it for me. It seems to be an open issue, see: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/141785912